# is there a fast circularly shift function for multi-dimension array in R

Tags: r, arrays, performance, circular-dependency, shift

I have three 4x4x1000 arrays A,B,C. I want to combine each 4x4 from A,B,C to generate 1 billion combinations. I am currently trying to circular shift the array B and C along the 3rd dimension but my code (in R) is very slow and takes ~6 minutes to run, while similar code on matlab only takes ~4s. However, all my other codes are in R and I wonder if there is a faster way to run this in R? Thanks a lot.

```
m=4
n=1000
a1=array(runif(m*m*n,0,1), c(m,m,n))
a2=a1
a3=a1
Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n) {
  for (j in 1:n) {
    a3 = abind(a3[,,2:n],a3[,,1])
  }
  a2 = abind(a2[,,2:n],a2[,,1])

}
Sys.time()
```

Comment: you do not need to bind two arrays. just index the original array with an appropriate array of indices. Also, "codes" is grammatically incorrect when one talks about computer code. (as opposed to, say, launch codes).

Comment: As @Tasos mentions, `a3[,,c(2:n,1)]` should be equivalent to `abind(a3[,,2:n],a3[,,1])` and will save you an order of magnitude of running time.

Comment: Thanks! The process time now drops to 100 second. I wonder if there is anything else I can do to improve?

Comment: Why do you need to circular shift them? What should your final output look like?

Comment: @user12670995 currently you are getting the same object as `a1` ( `a1 = a2 = a3`). Is this what you want? Then whats the point?

Answer (score 0):

```
# more simplified example:
m = 2
n = 3
a1 = array(1:(m*m*n), c(m,m,n))
a1
```

To do "circular shift", we do not need to physically change data n times.
We can simply calculate the end indexes and subset the data once.

For example, we want to shift 2 times:

```
n3 <- 2
new_ind <- c((1:n)[-(1:n3)], (1:n)[1:n3]) # calculate indices
new_ind
# [1] 3 1 2

a2_v2 = a1[,,new_ind] # one subset
a2_v2
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    9   11
# [2,]   10   12
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    5    7
# [2,]    6    8
```

P.S. There is no point in shifting `n` (3`d dimension size) times,
as we will get the initial data (that is what you did in your example).